Existing tool to verify LLM output on-chain?
I am building a prediction application that requires some non-biased "judge" to compare different pieces of text. I'd like to use an LLM as part of this process, but obviously would need some way to verify the authenticity of the output on-chain. Do any tools like this exist? I struggled to find anything solid online.
